# Can notification permissions be disabled via adb command?

Tags: android, adb

I am running some tests for an Android app, and I need to disable notification permissions, but since tests ran on different devices, I need to do it with some command because interacting with UI is not a good approach.

Is there any adb command which allows to enable/disable notifications for a specific app?

I was tried running `adb shell cmd notification disallow_listener app.package.name` but I get this message in response and it does not work: `Invalid listener - must be a ComponentName`

Answer (score 1):

If it's on Android 13 and you mean to disable showing notifications, that's a normal permission now, so you can reject it and grant it:

```
adb shell pm revoke APP_PACKAGE_NAME android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
adb shell pm grant APP_PACKAGE_NAME  android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
```

If below Android 12, I can't find how to do it, but I reported about it so that it will be written if it's possible:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/281313347

Answer (score -1):

For granting and denying to get a notification ability to your app service you can use as following code in cmd

To allow listening and receiving your ExampleService (which is a service for notification listeners)

```
adb shell cmd notification allow_listener app.package.name/app.package.name.subfolder.ExampleService
```

and to disallow it

```
adb shell cmd notification allow_listener app.package.name/app.package.name.subfolder.ExampleService
```

***The point for your question that you must specify your service listener path**

Comment: I think the question is about disable notifications for a given app, not the ability for the app to listen to get other notifications from other apps.